# How to inherit from my custom class

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance

I have created a class in Qt that has a number of public properties lets say

```
class items
{
public:
    QString name;
    QString description;
```

How can I create a new class that inherits all the variables and methods from this class?

Comment: class derived : public items isn't it?

Comment: Don't ask me :P, what I did is **class newItem: public items** but I am not sure I understand it correctly. Class 'items' has its own constructor, where does that get called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is about c++ not Qt. You can search c++ documents to learn about [c++ inheritance](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_inheritance.htm).

You can inherit another class in this way:

```
class myClass : public items
{
    myClass() : Item()
    {
       //
    }
}
```

Comment: I do know some c++, and I was trying to redo this tutorial (http://www.penguinprogrammer.co.uk/rpg-tutorial-2/items/), but got somewhat confused by line **10|Weapon(std::string name, std::string description, int damage, double hitRate) : Item(name, description)**

Comment: In constructor of myClass call constructor of item.